# Postgres: How to remove duplicates of old records in log table

Tags: postgresql, performance, logging, indexing, duplicates

I have a log table with about 5 million records:

```
  id BIGSERIAL, 
  object_type_name VARCHAR(255), 
  object_id BIGINT, 
  user_id BIGINT,
  service_id BIGINT,
  op_id INTEGER,
  dt TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
  property_name VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT object_log_object_log_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

I need to delete duplicate records leaving only the latest record (the one with the max `id`). The problem is that my query is very slow (> 1 min):

```
DELETE FROM sys.object_log AS t5 
 USING (
   SELECT t3.id 
     FROM sys.object_log t3 LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT t1.id 
         FROM sys.object_log t1 
        WHERE t1.id = ( 
              SELECT max(t2.id) 
                FROM sys.object_log t2 
               WHERE t2.object_type_name = t1.object_type_name 
                 AND t2.object_id = t1.object_id
                 AND t2.property_name = t1.property_name 
              )
     ) t4 ON t3.id=t4.id 
   WHERE t4.id IS NULL
 ) t6 
 WHERE t5.id = t6.id
```

**QUERY PLAN**

```
Delete on object_log t5  (cost=1.30..72821293.06 rows=8298362 width=18)
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=1.30..72821293.06 rows=8298362 width=18)
        Merge Cond: (t3.id = t5.id)
        ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.86..72365877.02 rows=8298362 width=20)
              Merge Cond: (t3.id = t1.id)
              ->  Index Scan using object_log_object_log_pkey on object_log t3  (cost=0.43..330836.36 rows=8340062 width=14)
              ->  Index Scan using object_log_object_log_pkey on object_log t1  (cost=0.43..72013669.25 rows=41700 width=14)
                    Filter: (id = (SubPlan 1))
                    SubPlan 1
                      ->  Aggregate  (cost=8.58..8.59 rows=1 width=8)
                            ->  Index Only Scan using object_log_idx1 on object_log t2  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=8)
                                  Index Cond: ((object_type_name = (t1.object_type_name)::text) AND (object_id = t1.object_id) AND (property_name = (t1.property_name)::text))
        ->  Index Scan using object_log_object_log_pkey on object_log t5  (cost=0.43..330836.36 rows=8340062 width=14)
```

Any idea how to improve performance ?

**UPD.1**

Next query is also slow:

```
DELETE FROM sys.object_log
    WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS rnum
        FROM sys.object_log
        WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY object_type_name, object_id, property_name ORDER BY id)
        ) t
    WHERE t.rnum > 1)
```

**QUERY PLAN**

```
QUERY PLAN
Delete on object_log  (cost=1703454.67..1960873.74 rows=2780021 width=38)
  ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1703454.67..1960873.74 rows=2780021 width=38)
        Hash Cond: (object_log.id = t.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on object_log  (cost=0.00..197648.62 rows=8340062 width=14)
        ->  Hash  (cost=1668704.40..1668704.40 rows=2780021 width=40)
              ->  Subquery Scan on t  (cost=1355952.08..1668704.40 rows=2780021 width=40)
                    Filter: (t.rnum > 1)
                    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1355952.08..1564453.63 rows=8340062 width=38)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=1355952.08..1376802.23 rows=8340062 width=30)
                                Sort Key: object_log_1.object_type_name, object_log_1.object_id, object_log_1.property_name, object_log_1.id
                                ->  **Seq Scan** on object_log object_log_1  (cost=0.00..197648.62 rows=8340062 width=30)
```

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates

Hope you find it useful.
Bjarni